# Django ModelChoiceField optgroup tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-forms

How can I  set in ModelChoiceField **optgroup** tag?

This is example:

**models.py**

```
class Link(models.Model):
    config = models.ForeignKey(Config)
    name = models.URLField(u'Name', null=True, max_length=50)
    gateway = models.IPAddressField(u'Gateway', null=True)
    weight = models.IntegerField(u'Weight', null=True)
    description = models.TextField(u'Description', blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
class LinkForm(ModelForm):
    config = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Config.objects.all(), empty_label="Choose a link",widget=GroupedSelect())

class Meta:
    model = Link
```

I would like to render my ChoiceField like this:

**example.html**

```
<select id="id_config" name="config">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Choose a link</option>
    <optgroup label="Configuration" >
        <option value="8">Address: 192.168.1.202/255.255.255.0 </option>
        <option value="9">Address: 192.168.1.240/255.255.255.0 </option>
        <option value="10">Address: 192.168.3.1/255.255.255.0 </option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

**UPDATE****

### I solved my problem like this:

```
class GroupedSelect(Select):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
        if value is None: value = ''
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
        output = [format_html('<select{0}>', flatatt(final_attrs))]
        for index, option_gp in enumerate(self.choices):
            if index == 0:
                option_value = smart_unicode(option_gp[0])
                option_label = smart_unicode(option_gp[1])
                output.append(u'<option value="%s">%s</option>' %  (escape(option_value), escape(option_label)))
                output.append('<optgroup label = "Configuration">')
            elif index!=0 and index <= len(self.choices):
                option_value = smart_unicode(option_gp[0])
                option_label = smart_unicode(option_gp[1])
                output.append(u'<option value="%s">%s</option>' % (escape(option_value), escape(option_label)))          
        output.append(u'</optgroup>')
        output.append(u'</select>')
        return mark_safe('\n'.join(output))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add optgroups to a django ModelMultipleChoiceField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737116/how-to-add-optgroups-to-a-django-modelmultiplechoicefield)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You don't need to create any custom field, Django already does the job, just pass the choices well formatted:

```
MEDIA_CHOICES = (
 ('Audio', (
   ('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),
   ('cd', 'CD'),
  )
 ),
 ('Video', (
   ('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),
   ('dvd', 'DVD'),
  )
 ),
)
```

Comment: If anyone wants to do multiple levels of nesting with ChoiceField, I wrote up a way to do it on my blog: http://www.mostthingsweb.com/2015/04/emulating-nested-optgroups-in-django-forms/

Comment: But this works with `ChoiceField`, not `ModelChoiceField` right?

Comment: He asked for ModelChoiceField and this does not resolve it. Wrong answer.

Answer (score 8):

`ModelChoiceField` uses a `ModelChoiceIterator` to convert the queryset to a list of choices.
You can easily override this class to introduce groups.
Here is an example that groups cities by country:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from django.forms.models import ModelChoiceField, ModelChoiceIterator
from .models import City

class CityChoiceIterator(ModelChoiceIterator):
    def __iter__(self):
        queryset = self.queryset.select_related('country').order_by('country__name', 'name')
        groups = groupby(queryset, key=lambda x: x.country)
        for country, cities in groups:
            yield [
                country.name,
                [
                    (city.id, city.name)
                    for city in cities
                ]
            ]

class CityChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    iterator = CityChoiceIterator

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(City.objects.all(), *args, **kwargs)
```

Note: I didn't have time to check that this technique is compatible with the new [`ModelChoiceIteratorValue`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoiceiteratorvalue) introduced in Django 3.1.

Comment: Didn't have to do anything extra than what you showed here for my 3.2 app... This is a very simple and practical solution for me... Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 3):

An extension of @Stefan Manastirliu answer to use with [django-categories](https://github.com/callowayproject/django-categories). (Downside is that `get_tree_data()` function below allows only one level) . In combination with javascript plugins like [bootstrap multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) you can get multi-select like [image: this]

**Models.py**

```
from categories.models import CategoryBase
class SampleCategory(CategoryBase):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'sample categories'

class SampleProfile(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('myapp.SampleCategory')
```

**forms.py**

```
from myapp.models import SampleCategory

    def get_tree_data():
        def rectree(toplevel):
            children_list_of_tuples = list()
            if toplevel.children.active():
                for child in toplevel.children.active():
                    children_list_of_tuples.append(tuple((child.id,child.name)))

            return children_list_of_tuples

        data = list()
        t = SampleCategory.objects.filter(active=True).filter(level=0)
        for toplevel in t:
            childrens = rectree(toplevel)
            data.append(
                tuple(
                    (
                        toplevel.name,
                        tuple(
                            childrens
                            )
                        ) 
                    )
            )
        return tuple(data)

class SampleProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=get_tree_data())
    class Meta:
        model = SampleProfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good snippet:

Choice Field and Select Widget With Optional Optgroups: 
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/200/

Comment: Yap, that is really good snippet. I followed these instructions... Tnxx

Answer (score 1):

In your form.py, you need to use a `ChoiceField` or a `MultipleChoiceField`
instead of a `ModelChoiceField` if you want to use the Django built-in "choices" that natively handles the optgroup:

**models.py**

```
class Config(models.Model):
    label = models.Charfield(verbose_name="Config",max_length=20,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label

class Link(models.Model):
    config = models.ForeignKey(Config)
    name = models.URLField(u'Name', null=True, max_length=50)
    gateway = models.IPAddressField(u'Gateway', null=True)
    weight = models.IntegerField(u'Weight', null=True)
    description = models.TextField(u'Description', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
class LinkForm(ModelForm):
    config = forms.ChoiceField(label="Config")

class Meta:
    model = Link

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["config"].choices = [
        ["Configuration", [[c.id, c.label] for c in Config.objects.all()]]
    ]
```