# Django Admin: group by foreign key

Tags: django, django-admin

Lets say I have model Book that has foreign key to model Author, now I would like to modify Django admin to list the books like this

- Some Author

  - book 1
  - other book
- some other author

  - his first book
  - his last book

Is this possible in the admin interface?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15210511

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin) will not suffice, then I think your only option is to create a [custom admin view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites). Possibly use [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) to handle multiple formsets there.